# Parse and add multiple annotations?

Tags: ios, mkmapview

i have a Problem with the Annotiations, the Code is ok, but i read with the Variable [i] more than one Username and Location. On the Map i have only the last reading Username and Location Pin.
In the Debug Box , he show me all Names and Location, but i have only 1 Pin on the Map.

Here is the Code.

```
for (int i=1; i<4; ++i) {
[User whereKey:@"index" equalTo:@(i)];
PFObject *test1 = [User getFirstObject];
ann.title = [test1 objectForKey:@"username"] ;
PFGeoPoint *geopoint = [test1 objectForKey:@"currentLocation"];
CLLocationCoordinate2D coord = { geopoint.latitude, geopoint.longitude };
ann.coordinate = coord;

    [MapView addAnnotation:ann];


}
```

Thanks for your Help ;)

Answer (score 1):

The `ann` object which you are adding to the map needs to be created *separately* for each annotation that you add.

In the code shown, the `ann` object is not being created *inside* the `for` loop for each annotation so you end up with only one annotation object with the coordinates of the last item.

Create the `ann` object (alloc+init) inside the loop before setting the properties on it.